# FPDF responsive

Tags: php, responsive, fpdf

Estoy generando un pdf con la libreria fpdf y todo genial, pero los enunciados salen a medias, mochos, y como no es estático, la información del texto puede variar sin depender de mí, así que busco alguna forma o libreria para volver responsive el pdf, que no se salgan del pdf las letras.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

                                $archivo=file_get_contents("leer.txt"); 
                                $pdf = new FPDF();
                                $pdf->AddPage();
        $fecha=date("d") . " del " . date("m") . " de " . date("Y");
        $empresa='thinksec';
        $domicilio='este es el domicilio de la empresa';
        $domempleado='Domicilio del empleado';
        $salario=5000;
        $nomemp='El nombre del empleado es este';
        $nombre='el nombre es estexd ';
        $buscar=array("*fecha*", "*EMPRESA*", "*EMPLEADO*", "*DOMICILIO*", "*DOMEMPLEADO*", "*NOMEMP*","*SALARIO*");
        $reemplazar=array($fecha,$empresa, $nombre, $domicilio, $domempleado, $nomemp, $salario);
        $reemp=str_replace($buscar, $reemplazar, $archivo);


                    $convert = explode("\n", $reemp);
                    for($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++)  
                    {

                        $saltodelinea = nl2br($convert[$i]);
                        $pdf->SetX(80);
                        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
                        $pdf->Cell(50,4,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252'," ". $saltodelinea. " "), 0 ,2,"C");


                    }

                      $pdf->Output();
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en vez de usar "Cell" usa "MultiCell" (https://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/multicell.htm), así el texto se ajustará automáticamente.

Comment: Hola pues si funciona pero ahora me lo muestra muy delgado me refiero a que escribe maximo 4 palabras y hace un salto de linea, dejando los extremos en blanco y muy largo, sabras la solución asi coloque esa parte

 ` $saltodelinea = nl2br($convert[$i]);
         $pdf->SetX(80);
         $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
         $pdf->MultiCell(65,6,iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252'," ". $saltodelinea. " "), 0 ,"C",0);`

Comment: Creo que ya sobra el "for", simplemente carga el texto en el multicell. Prueba y me cuentas

Comment: No, si hago eso me muestra todo en blanco pues no recorre el arreglo

Comment: Y de hecho si le quito todo  y pongo la variable $remp directamente en MutliCell me lo muestra exactamente igual

Comment: Listo al parecer estaba dando mal el parametro del ancho(W) y en X disminui a 5.

Comment: No habia trabajado mucho con esta libreria pero lei la documentacion en: https://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/multicell.htm

Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Que bueno que haya podido colaborar

Comment: A la próxima, ponle un ejemplo pequeño para que el OP y los que vengan no dependan de que el enlace se rompa o no y, de paso, el OP se ahorraba pelear con la declaración del MultiCell.